# Laravel where is "extend" method for "Validator" declared

Tags: laravel, validation, customvalidator

I will give an analogy to explain what I want:

For example, if I want to read about the "behaviour" of the `save()` method in:

```
$model->save();
```

then I can go to *`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`*

to read what's inside

```
public function save() {....}
```

**QUESTION:** If I want to know the behaviour of `extend()` in

```
Validator::extend('','');
```

Where in the system laravel files should I go?

Thank you in advance!:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facades are a bit harder to find than other classes, since they only reference a service container binding. You'd have to find the class where this binding is registered to find the backing class.

The easiest way, for official facades, is to just check the [Facades Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/facades), there is a list of facades and their backing classes at the bottom:

```
Validator   Illuminate\Validation\Factory   validator
```

So the Validator facade resolves to the class `Illuminate\Validation\Factory` which is bound to the service container with the name `validator`. From here on, it should be easy to find the `Illuminate\Validation\Factory` class in your vendor directory.

Comment: thank you. So, in my Laravel 5.4 I did like this: 
1) opened 'app/config/app.php', 
2) found  ''aliases' and found there ' 'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class".
3) in ' Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator", it's written: "@see \Illuminate\Validation\Factory"
4) in " \Illuminate\Validation\Factory" I found the "extend" method.
Thank you again.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know they linked the correct class in their docblock. That works too I guess.